# How to use orderby on timestamp in JPAQuery?

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

```
JPAQuery<String> query = jpaQueryFactory.select(userEntity.id);
query.from(userEntity);      
query.orderBy(userEntity.createdAt)
```

In the above code I cannot call asc() for createdAt since it's of type SimplePath. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Never used QueryDSL, but [orderBy](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/support/QueryBase.html#orderBy(com.mysema.query.types.OrderSpecifier)) signature is

```
public Q orderBy(OrderSpecifier<?>... o)
```

So it expects one or several `OrderSpecifier` as argument. Clicking on OrderSpecifier leads to [this documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/OrderSpecifier.html), showing the following constructor:

```
public OrderSpecifier(Order order, Expression<T> target)
```

`Order` is a simple enum. Clicking on `Expression` leads to [this documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/Expression.html), which lists all the implementing classes of that interface. And among them is `SimplePath`, which is the type of the property that you're trying to order by.

The javadoc is quite a useful resource, and is pretty simple to navigate. Use it.